# Dropping rows into selected divs with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, drag-and-drop

I started using jqGrid some weeks ago. It looked as if it can do all I need (basic stuff). Now my ambitions have grown a little and I would like to drag individual rows out of their grid and drop their ID into a div that is part of a grid of many divs. It is like allocating some information contained in the jqGrid row into a div which lives outside that jqGrid. Is this possible with jqGrid? if yes, how please? If not, can you please point me in the right direction?